# Customize action when button is pressed on an external harddrive

Tags: external-hard-drive, script, automation, reverse-engineer

I have a [Transcend StoreJet](http://www.transcend-info.com/products/Catlist.asp?modno=293&cat_no=190) external harddrive. It has a button on the outer shell which is used for synchronizing folders and files when it is pressed. There is a software that enables this function. But I want to customize this button so it triggers a .cmd or .bat file.

Is there any way to achieve this? Or would you assume that it is some proprietary implementation?

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention... It is meant to run on Windows 7. Up to now I tried nothing because I have no programming knowledge nor I know where to start searching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my past experiences with HDD enclosures with buttons, I would assume it's proprietary as it probably requires a custom driver and their software would need to facilitate you launching things.

As you state you have no programming knowledge, then writing your own driver to interface with the hardware is probably out of the question. :)

A suggestion:

Use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to determine what program file is being launched when you push the button, and then replace that file with your own executable.

Comment: I assume replacing the executable with my own programm is done with or in Process Monitor. Is that right?

Comment: No, it'll be a file on your hard drive.  Once you figure out what file it's launching (via Process Monitor), replace that file (via Explorer, or the command line).